# string replace two matches that have an exact (partly) match within one string

Tags: php

I have a variable `$text` which is a plain text that can contain one or more email addresses in a line of text. I use a regular expression to find these email addresses and then transform them into clickable `<a href="mailto:....etc` addresses. This is my code with an example that work fine:

```
$text = "this is the text that has a email@email.com in it and also test@email.com.";

if(preg_match_all('/[\p{L}0-9_.-]+@[0-9\p{L}.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6}\b/u',$text,$mails)){

foreach($mails[0] as $mail ){
    $text = str_replace($mail,'<a href="mailto:'.$mail.'">'.$mail.'</a>',$text);
    }
}
```

Or see this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/gMF8F). Problems occur when in my variable `$text` there are two email adresses that have an exact (partial) match. For example `sometest@email.com` and `test@email.com`. Here's another [live demo](https://3v4l.org/fNma8). The problem is the string replace happens within the partial match as well (because it is also a full match). How to bypass this issue?

Comment: You can’t really fix that, as long as you replace all matches in a separate loop afterwards. This should rather use preg_replace to begin with to do the replacing “in situ”.

Comment: If you're going preg way why not use preg_replace?

Comment: I need to replace the matches with themselves wrapped in an <a> element. How would I do that with preg_replace?

Comment: I put a answer down below, the only thing you might have to change is {2,3} to {2,?} where '?' would be changed to the top level domain range you want to support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)?
`str_replace` can overwrite previous matches.

This should be good for you:

```
echo preg_replace(
    '/([\p{L}0-9_.-]+@[0-9\p{L}.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6}\b)/u',
    '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>',
    $text
);
```

Notice that I had to slightly modify the regular expression and wrap it in parentheses.
This is so that I can reference it in the replacement.

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/i1dYH)

Comment: You can get away without changing the regex if you use `$0` in the replacement instead of `$1`

Comment: @Nick I did not know that! How does that work? `$0` assumes the entire pattern? It's funny that I was writing an edit about wrapping the pattern and you comment that ;D

Comment: Yes, `$0` refers to the entire match, just as `$match[0]` contains the entire match in a call to `preg_match(...,...,$match)`

Comment: I was just writing an answer using `$0` when you posted so decided not to bother. This is obviously therefore the best answer so +1

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch the caracter before your match to be sure it's a full match :

```
if(preg_match_all('/(.)([\p{L}0-9_.-]+@[0-9\p{L}.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6}\b)/u',$text,$mails))
```

-----------------------------------^

Then you just have to modify a bit your str_replace parameter
               var_dump($mails);

```
$id = 0;
foreach($mails[2] as $mail ){
   $text = str_replace($mails[1][$id].$mail,'$mails[1][$id].<a href="mailto:'.$mail.'">'.$mail.'</a>',$text);
   $id ++;
}
```

For example : https://3v4l.org/qYpHo

Answer (score 1):

Like so...

```
<?php

$string = "this is the text that has a email@email.com in it and also test@email.com.";

$search = array ( "!(\s)([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})!i",  
"!^([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})!i" );

$replace = array ( "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2\">\\2</a>", 
"<a href=\"mailto:\\1\">\\1</a>" );

echo preg_replace ( $search, $replace, $string );

?>
```

result...

```
this is the text that has a <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a> in it and also <a href="mailto:test@email.com">test@email.com</a>.
```